# Resize dynamically created div around its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create div like this:

```
$(ndiv).addClass("table").html(table.Table.Name).appendTo($("#tables"));
```

I'd like to be able to set its width to exactly fit table.Table.Name string.
Is something like that possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what exactly is `ndiv`

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution would be to wrap the string in a `span` element and pick the width from that

```
$(ndiv).addClass("table").html('<span>' + table.Table.Name + '</span>').appendTo($("#tables"));
var w = $('span', ndiv).width()
$(ndiv).width(w);
```

Answer (score 1):

If **table.Table.Name** string is table tag with content, you can try this code:

```
var $block = $(ndiv).addClass("table").html(table.Table.Name).appendTo($("#tables"));
$block.width($block.children("table").width());
```

Or you can try simple way, without js, if you page-proofs than allow. Set CSS:

```
.table{display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: it's just string in json object